# Array length does not match index length using the Random Forests Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, jupyter-notebook

I have tried to debug the following code but kept giving me ValueError.

`output = pd.DataFrame({'PassengerId' : test_datasets.PassengerId, 'Survived': predictions}) output.to_csv('gender_predict.csv', Index=False) print("Your submission was successfully saved!") output`

Even though Index length is False (non-considered). Still I kept getting the following errors

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[22], line 1
----> 1 output = pd.DataFrame({'PassengerId' : test_datasets.PassengerId, 'Survived': predictions})
      2 output.to_csv('gender_predict.csv', Index=False)
      3 print("Your submission was successfully saved!")

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:664, in DataFrame.__init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    658     mgr = self._init_mgr(
    659         data, axes={"index": index, "columns": columns}, dtype=dtype, copy=copy
    660     )
    662 elif isinstance(data, dict):
    663     # GH#38939 de facto copy defaults to False only in non-dict cases
--> 664     mgr = dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy, typ=manager)
    665 elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
    666     import numpy.ma.mrecords as mrecords

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py:493, in dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype, typ, copy)
    489     else:
    490         # dtype check to exclude e.g. range objects, scalars
    491         arrays = [x.copy() if hasattr(x, "dtype") else x for x in arrays]
--> 493 return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, dtype=dtype, typ=typ, consolidate=copy)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py:118, in arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, dtype, verify_integrity, typ, consolidate)
    115 if verify_integrity:
    116     # figure out the index, if necessary
    117     if index is None:
--> 118         index = _extract_index(arrays)
    119     else:
    120         index = ensure_index(index)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py:680, in _extract_index(data)
    675     if lengths[0] != len(index):
    676         msg = (
    677             f"array length {lengths[0]} does not match index "
    678             f"length {len(index)}"
    679         )
--> 680         raise ValueError(msg)
    681 else:
    682     index = default_index(lengths[0])

ValueError: array length 179 does not match index length 418
```

Initially, there wasn't any errors until I tried to check the accuracy of the model using the `train_test_split()` to split the test and train data.
I tried to use the `pd.Series()`

Comment: Your predictions (on your test set) has length 179 but your passengerId series has length 418. You need to use the ids after your train/test split.